# How to capture events for dynamically created data-role="collapsible"

Tags: jquery-mobile

Could you please let me know how to capture the events for data-role="collapsible"

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5kbEE/18/

I have tried it this way

```
$('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function() {
        alert('herere');
});
```

How ever i observed that the above event is working fine in case the data-role="collapsible" is static one (http://jsfiddle.net/5kbEE/19/).

Could you please let me know how to make it work if it created dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**. The container handles the event and delegates it to the collapsible. In this way the collapsibles do not have to exist at the time the handler is created.

```
$(document).on('collapsibleexpand', '.my-collaspible', function () {
    alert('herere');
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5kbEE/21/)**